# Can I use BERT or Doc2Vec for comparing lists of potentially unrelated words?

Tags: nlp, data-science, cosine-similarity, bert-language-model, doc2vec

**Context**

I'm building a sample project to match users with similar interests. Given any two users with a given list of interests, I'd like to create a similarity score between those users. It seems like the right way to do this is convert interests into vectors using NLP then compare using cosine similarity.

**Question**

Can I use BERT (ex: [BERT as a service](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service)) or Doc2Vec (ex: [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html)) to create a single vector for each user's list of interests?

Ex: an input of `user_interests = ['python', 'photography', 'running']` would produce a single vector representing all the user's interests which could then be compared to other users' vectors using cosine similarity.

**Some key points I'm trying to suss through:**

- Given I'm trying to match two users, I'd ideally like to create a single similarity score (ex: I've also considered converting each interest into its own vector then comparing individual interests, but that results in multiple similarity score for any two users. I'm not certain what I would do next here.)
- Given that each list of interests could contain a number of unrelated terms ex: `user_interests = ['python', 'photography', 'running']` does it make sense to create a single vector for the full list of terms?
- Given the same as above, is BERT / Doc2Vec a useful model for creating a vector?
- I'd like to maintain a high similarity score for two users with related but not equivalent interests ex: `user_interests_1 = ['python', 'photography', 'running']` should receive a high similarity score when compared to `user_interests_2 = ['coding', 'art', 'exercise']`